# Linking OIS in XCode on OSX with CMake

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, cmake

I'm creating a browser plugin that handles joystick input across all browser and platforms. It's working on Linux and Windows, but I'm having trouble linking to the OIS library in XCode.

I've built OIS and get libOIS.a and OIS.dylib and am linking them with CMake as follows:

```
find_library(CARBON NAMES Carbon)
find_library(IOKIT NAMES IOKit)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
 ${PLUGIN_INTERNAL_DEPS}
 ${CARBON}
 ${IOKIT}
 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libOIS.a"
)
```

But I'm still getting errors every time I try to use the OIS classes from my code and build the project:

```
ld warning: in /Users/Lana/Documents/STRd6/boomsticks/Boomstick/lib/libOIS.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file

Undefined symbols:
 "OIS::InputManager::destroyInputSystem(OIS::InputManager*)", referenced from:
     JoysticksHandler::~JoysticksHandler()in Joysticks.o
     JoysticksHandler::~JoysticksHandler()in Joysticks.o
 "OIS::InputManager::createInputSystem(std::multimap<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)", referenced from:
     JoysticksHandler::initialize()       in Joysticks.o
 "OIS::InputManager::enableAddOnFactory(OIS::InputManager::AddOnFactories)", referenced from:
     JoysticksHandler::initialize()       in Joysticks.o
 "OIS::InputManager::getNumberOfDevices(OIS::Type)", referenced from:
     JoysticksHandler::initialize()       in Joysticks.o
 "typeinfo for OIS::Exception", referenced from:
     GCC_except_table44 in Joysticks.o
 "OIS::InputManager::createInputObject(OIS::Type, bool, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
     JoysticksHandler::initialize()       in Joysticks.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know anything about XCode, but I was able to get the same code building with a very similar process on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

The linker warning here gives you a clue:

```
ld warning: in /...k/lib/libOIS.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
```

The linker is telling you that you're trying to link in a library file that has no implementation for the x86_64 architecture. How did you build that library?

Either you're building a universal binary executable, and the symbols are just not there for the x86_64 version... or perhaps you have a header file for a newer version of the library, but have not updated the .a file, and the symbols you reference in your application code just don't exist in the .a file in your source tree...